The gradients of a sub-level set of a convex function is the convex hull of the gradients of the associated level set.
This feels like it should be a known result, I am trying to generalize it (if true) to use in some convergence proof of a paper I am currently writing.

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be a continuously differentiable convex function with some minimizer $x^\ast$, then for any $x\in\mathbb R^n$
\begin{align*}
\{ \nabla f(y) : f(y)\leq f(x) \} = \overline{\operatorname{conv}} \{ \nabla f(y) : f(y)= f(x) \}
\end{align*}

Where $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} A$ is the closed convex hull of $A$.
This feels intuitively true but turns out to be a bit difficult for me to prove.
My main struggle is with proveing that $\{ \nabla f(y) : f(y)\leq f(x) \}$ is convex.
